# postman giving 400 bad request when i use global varibales how to solve this

Tags: api, rest, postman

when i use normal json body postman gives me **201 created response** but when i am using global variable postman giving me **400 bad request**

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you please provide a [mre]? See [ask] for further guidance on asking questions. Please [edit] to add transcriptions of your images of text into actual text. [See here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/11107541) for why. See [/editing-help](/editing-help#code) for how to format code blocks.

Comment: Can you try put quotes in the JSON like `"{{email}}"`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Variables still need to  be used in proper JSON format therefore you should be putting your strings in quotes:

```
{
  "email": "{{email}}",
  "password" : "{{password}}",
  "confirmpassword" : "{{confirmpassword}}"
}
```

See https://learning.postman.com/docs/sending-requests/variables/

---

Side note: please provide actual "happy path" (when it worked) as well as your errors.  Text instead of images is good too to help people try to reproduce your errors without a lot of typing